# A Question Regarding Russell's Paradox

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic, paradox, bertrand-russell

Consider the 'set' behind Russell's Paradox:

R = { *x* | *x* is a set and *x* ∉ *x* }

in light of Cantor's definition of set ("aggregate"/Menge) in his CONTRIBUTIONS TO THE FOUNDING OF THE THEORY OF TRANSFINITE NUMBERS (Dover edition),

> By an 'aggregate'...we are to understand any collection into a whole... M of definite and separate objects m of our intuition or our thought.  These objects are called the 'elements' of M.

One should note that in this definition, 'objecthood' is primary.

Considering R once again, R certainly has elements and according to Cantor's definition of set can definitely be considered one.  Let me now ask the question that leads us into Russell's Paradox:

"Is R a member of R?"

Because R has elements, it can definitely be considered a 'definite and separate object of our intuition or our thought' and as such can seemingly
have certain attributes satisfying it and others not satisfying it.

Russell's Paradox is that assuming 'R is not a member of R' implies 'R is a member of R', which implies again 'R is not a member of R'.

Since R's 'objecthood' is primary, why doesn't it make sense to say that R can neither have the attributes '__ is a member of R', nor not-'__ is a member of R' correctly attributed to it?  If this is the case then Russell's Paradox is dissolved, since it is the assumption that R must satisfy either '__ is a member of R' or not-'__ is a member of R' that seemingly gets us into the paradox to begin with.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you may find Leśniewski's mereology interesting as it is to a significant degree motivated by Russell's paradox (as well as Leśniewski's aversion to the empty set and, by virtue of his nominalism, his insistence that singletons are equal to their lone members i.e. x = {x}).

Comment: @danielm:  You are right--'naive' mereology is very applicable to Russell's paradox and the continuum as well.  For example, assume the world is at base nothing but 'gunk' (i.e., 'gunk' is primary) and one constructs entities via their attributes out of the 'gunk'.  Construct the Russell Set R from the 'gunk' and R can neither be nor not be a member of itself (i.e. those attributes cannot be attributed to R).  Regarding the continuum, it cannot be defined as a set of points so the Continuum Hypothesis is false.

Answer (score 7):

> Since R's 'objecthood' is primary, why doesn't it make sense to say that R can neither have the attributes `is a member of R` nor not-`is a member of R` correctly attributed to it? If this is the case then Russell's Paradox is dissolved, since it is the assumption that R must satisfy either `is a member of R` or not-'`is a member of R` that seemingly gets us into the paradox to begin with.

If I understand your question correctly, you don't want to declare these membership relations to be [undecidable statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorem#Meaning_of_the_first_incompleteness_theorem) (as the other answers seem to interpret your question); you want to restrict the collection `R` not to have a set membership relation.

## Good news, you just discovered proper classes!

Leaving aside the remark about Cantor's "objecthood", which I could't really follow, your intuition leads you in the right direction.

Let's analyse the situation:

`R = { x : x ∉ x }` yielding `R ∉ R ⇔ R ∈ R` could be obtained in set theory because an informal [unrestricted comprehension principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension) was being used. Hence, the problem can be dealt with by carefully restricting the comprehension principle. That's exactly how it's being done in [contemporary set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFC), using an [axiom schema of **restricted** comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). The result is that ZFC doesn't allow to define `R`, or, to state it more exactly, `R` can be defined as a *reductio ad absurdum* to prove that the "set of all sets" doesn't exist, i.e. assuming its existence leads to the contradiction described by Russell's paradox.

The salient point, however, is that what the proof really tells us is that **the set of all sets cannot be a set**. In fact, Russell's paradox, as well as [Cantor's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_paradox) and [Burali-Forti paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox) all tell us simply that **some collections, like "the set of all sets" are not sets**. The father of set theory, [Georg Cantor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor), thought of these collections, which he called "[absolute infinities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Infinite)" as beyond the reach of mathematics and went mystical about them. As it turns out, this evaluation was too pessimistic. The kind of collections which Cantor called "absolute infinities" are known today as ***[proper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory))***. (You may consult additionally this [brief introduction](http://planetmath.org/Class.html)).

Simply put, the concept of **class** can be introduced this way:

> A class `x` is a set iff there is a class `y` such that `x ∈ y`. A class which is not a set is said to be a proper class.

Now, suppose that `R ∉ R`. If you suppose that R is a set, you get a contradiction, so `R` **must be a proper class**.

In ZFC we can talk about proper classes only *informally*. However, there are alternative foundational systems, known also as **class theories**, which - surprise! - allow to treat proper classes formally beside sets. The most "explicit" of these systems is [Morse–Kelley set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory), which admits proper classes as basic object alongside with sets. But there are [many other approaches](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/).

---

See also:

- [Set of all sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_of_all_sets)
- [Universal set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set)
- ["proper classes" questions over at math.sx](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22proper+class%22&submit=search)

Some notable proper classes:

- [Constructible universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe)
- [Von Neumann universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe)

Comment: Okay, so I read everything after "Good news...!" in Professor Farnsworth's voice.

Comment: … For the uninitiated: [Good news everyone!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1D1cap6yETA)

Comment: @DBK:  What I am trying to say is that R is still a set, because it can still be a member of some class y--it just can neither be nor not be a member of itself--those attributes just don't apply to R.  What Russell himself says is that R does not form a totality (which is of course correct assuming excluded middle).  What I am saying is that classical logic may not be the proper logic for Naive set theory, just as classical logic may not be the proper logic for quantum systems.  I hope this clarifies--not confuses.

Comment: @Thomas: My bad. But what you are trying to say in set theoretic terms is that a certain set membership relation shouldn't selectively apply, namely between the set and itself. (It is still not clear if we ought to exclude every set from applying to itself or just R). **This is a completely arbitrary and ad hoc restriction**. Also, I don't understand what this has to do with LEM in general. But even assuming that it is somehow connected, that's still not a departure from classical logic because in all other membership relations LEM should still hold, following your line of thought.

Comment: @Thomas: The closest "object" fulfilling your restriction I can think of is an [**urelement**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement). **These urelements are the "definite and separate objects" Cantor is referring to in his definition, but they are not sets to begin with**. And an urelement `U` is actually defined as not having any elements, so - in your parlance - ∉ can still "be predicated" of `U`.

Comment: @DBK: Also, I have reconsidered your definition of proper class: "A class x is a set iff there is a class y such that x 'is a member of' y. A class which is not a set is called a proper class".  This seems to imply that R cannot be a member of any class because if it is then it by definition must be a member of itself but then the contradiction exists again, so the only way out of the contradiction is to conclude that the attributes '___ is a member of R', '___ is not a member of R' do not apply to R.  This is somewhat analogous to saying, with Brouwer, that the google'th digit of pi is 1

Comment: can be neither 0 nor 1 because we haven't calculated the googleth digit of pi yet.  If that can be a reason for saying LEM doesn't apply to the gooleth digit of pi (and intuitionists do hold this view for just this reason) then LEM certainly does not apply to R (yet R exists).  Regarding your comment on urelements, you are getting close to understanding what I mean by 'objecthood'.  Remember, Cantor's definition of set/Menge/aggregate states that it is "any collection into a whole M of definite and separate objects m of our intuition or our thought".

Comment: Since M is "a definite and separate object m of our intuition or our thought", it has 'objecthood' and as such can have attributes A(M) which can be abstracted from M but if this is the case then M can also have attributes A'(x) which neither apply nor not apply to M.  This seems to suggest that saying that neither '___ is a member of R' nor '___ is not a member of R' apply to R is neither completely arbitrary nor ad hoc, but rather a valid discovery in Naive Set Theory, one that Cantor could have, and should have discovered.

Comment: Think of it this way:  in Vedantic phiolsophy, Brahman can be thought of as having all attributes yet no attributes but that is the problem with thinking about Brahman....

Comment: Consider, too, Frege's basic law V (as translated by J.L. Bell in his course notes "The Philosophy of Mathematics):

Comment: ^f=^g iff (x)[f(x) = g(x)], where ^f,^g are the 'course-of-values of 'f' and 'g'(Bell defines 'course-of-values' as follows, "if f and g assign the same objects to all possible values of their arguments, we would say that that they both hve the same course of values; if f and g are concepts, we would say that they both have the same extension." He also says that in the Grundgesetze, the logical universe "comprises two sorts of entity:  functions and objects."  "Any function f associates with each value x of its argument an object f(x):  if this object is always one of the two truth values

Comment: 0 (false) or 1 (true), then f is called a concept or propositional function, and when f(x)=1 we say that x falls under the concept f."  Let's ask ourselves, what are the propositional functions of the Russell set R, -R (let -R be the symbol for the complement of R)?  By the Russell paradox, it would seem that the value of the propositional functions for the course-of-values R,-R would be both 0 and 1, but then on the one hand, if the propositional 'function' for the course-of-values' R,-R would not act as a function (in the modern sense of the term--though possibly in Frege's

Comment: sense of the term) then by the definition of the universe of the Grundgesetze neither R nor -R can be part of the extension of R, -R and Basic Law V holds for the natural restriction that f,g are functions in the modern sense; on the other, if one defines f to be the propositional function f of ''x 'is a member of' R" and g be the propositional function of "x 'is not a member of' R" then f(R)=g(-R)=f(-R)=g(R) so in some sense Basic Law V seems to 'hold' for R,-R as well (though 'complement' is not well-defined) which is to be expected if Basic Law V is deemed a 'law of logic'....

Comment: @DBK:  Even if R is a proper class by your definition, Russell's paradox would still hold for R,-R because it still has, by your acceptance of LEM, to be either a member or not a member of itself unless you can produce a positive definition of class distinct from the notion of set.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin  This is a terribly excessive use of comments for exposition.  One of the solutions here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism seeks out a different basis for logic, and does not completely contain the LEM, on the basis that human logic is an evolved intuition, which may further evolve, something it cannot do if everything is already either true or false.

Comment: Actually, he is talking about ramification, and not about proper classes at all.  Read his analysis.  He is not saying R cannot be a member of anything.  He is saying that it cannot be a member of anything that was not defined after it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the Comprehension principle;

the "recipe" we follow for constructing a set:

M = { x : Fx }

Defining M to be the set of all objects x such that x has the property F.

Bertrand Russell wrote this recipe: R = {x : x ∉ x}

And a paradox arises if you ask if R is an element in R or not!

Therefore Cantor's Set Theory (and Frege's logical system) was proven inconsistent!

Invented by Cantor, the recipe needs adjustment and here's a suggestion.

M =  {x : x ∈ M IFF Fx}

Defining M to be the set of all objects x 
such that x is an element in M IFF x has the property F.

Now x cannot take R as a value in the formula:

R =  {x : 
Defining R to be the set of all objects x such that x is an element in R IFF x is not an element in x.
x ∈ R IFF x ∉ x}

And Cantor's Set Theory and Frege's logic are no longer proven to be inconsistent.

You can read more about the Original Set Theory here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory#Cantor's_theory

Answer to a comment by jobermark:

Its not "{x: Fx}" that defines "M". The original set constructor does not use the name of the set to be constructed. The naming takes place outside the constructor by use of the identity statement "M={x: Fx}". Enabling inconsistency when F(M) = "M ∉ M".

By using "M" as a metavariable appearing in both sides of the identity statement: M = {x : x ∈ M IFF Fx}, the question whether M is an element of M or not is taken care of INSIDE the set constructor by the contradiction "M ∈ M IFF M ∉ M "  and we can no longer make the outside claim that M MUST be an element of M if M is not an element in M.

Not familiar with Metavariables? See the definition of truth:"x" is true IFF x.

It seems Cantor was there before me! In a letter to Dedekind he discussed adjusting the Comprehension Principle ... Thomas Benjamin gives a modern version of Cantors adjusted theory:

Naive Set Theory:

Extensionality: Given two sets A and B , A=B iff (x)[x 'is a member of' A iff x is a member of' B]

Comprehension: Given any predicate P(x), the set {x|P(x)} exists and

(a)[a 'is a member of' {x|P(x)} iff P(a)]

And then Thomas asks if one can still derive paradoxes from this amended version of Cantors Naive Set Theory?

I asked only if Russell's Paradox can be derived!

The predicate is x ∉ x

The name of the set is {x|x ∉ x}

And the set constructor is: x ∈ {x|x ∉ x} IFF x ∉ x

And Cantor then would finally get that for no x is it true that x = {x|x ∉ x}!

But it is confusing to use "{x|x ∉ x}" as the name of the set to be constructed!

So when the predicate is defined as x ∉ x then I stipulate that R = {x|x ∉ x}

So I can have the set constructor with R inside {x|x ∈ R IFF x ∉ x}

And finally R = {x|x ∈ R IFF x ∉ x} (My version)

But we can eliminate R if we want Cantors version:

{x|x ∉ x} = {x| x ∈ {x|x ∉ x}  IFF x ∉ x}

Comment: I like your answer but a reference giving more information on the "Comprehension principle" would help the reader and strengthen your answer. A reference such as https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/ may be beneficial.

Comment: I did an edit to improve the essay after your suggestions.

Comment: Very good.  I edited to add in apostrophes and combined two lines since they were the same sentence. You can roll these back if you want.

Comment: NO! Im happy to get editor help!

Comment: OK, but M = {x: Fx} alreadly defines M as the set such that x is in M if and only if Fx is satisfied.  Your notation combines two equivalent things in a way that makes no sense. Where you have used it, M is not yet defined.  It cannot be used to establish its own definition by comprehension.  The set of dogs is obviously the set of things that are a dog and have four legs (ignoring the odd mishap), but that fails to define the set of dogs, which is clearly not the set of all things that have four legs.

Comment: Can you perhaps give your example about dogs a more formal dressing? I cant see that it would constitute a counter example. 
(Would you use a conjunction where I use an equivalence?)

Answer (score 1):

You have constructed R and now you ask whether R is a member of R. A positive or negative answer to this question leads to a contradiction. You are resolving it by saying R cannot have the properties: 'is a member of R' or not-'is a member of R'. This is absurd. It's like saying some statement cannot be 'true' or 'false'. Unless you are using some logic other than the standard one, no statement can be neither true nor false. (That is, every statement is true or false.)

Comment: You seem to assume attributes are predicates - if they weren't why need we assume excluded middle for them?  Suppose we say that each attribute R is associated with a predicate R', and then that R is an attribute of T when R'(T) is necessarily true.  Then excluded middle doesn't hold for these kind of attributes in general.

Comment: What about the [Continuum Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) by your namesake? I'm really curious, could it be that it is either true or false, but simply cannot be proven either way?

Comment: @CharlesStewart, I shouldn't have used the word attributes, I meant properties. Wrong or right, I think my answer is clear. The issue with the paradox is the definition of R, you cannot resolve it by saying R is a set for which neither of the two statements 'is a member of R' and not-'is a member of R' hold. Perhaps you should explain what you mean by attributes.

Comment: @Koeng, provability is another issue. It certainly cannot be both true and false (by the law of excluded middle).

Comment: But it seems to me that we are not talking about the excluded middle. I think it's different to say that something is "both true and false" and "neither true nor false". Or isn't it?

Comment: @Koeng, I have been a bit inaccurate I mixed up the laws of "noncontradiction" and "excluded middle". I am assuming the following three laws of classical logic: http://editthis.info/logic/The_Laws_of_Classical_Logic

Comment: The question talks of attributes and does not explain them.  I gave a modal interpretation of attribute for which the excluded middle does not hold.  I am bemused by the question, but I agree that you cannot stipulate your way out of a contradiction - if the question talked of satisfying rather than having attributes, I would not have commented.

Comment: One of the points I am trying to get at is that one cannot assume classical logic a priori (eg. quantum logic), but allow the domain of discourse to determine the laws of logic appropriate to it. If one assumes that sets are objects of our intuition or our thought that can be collected into a 'whole', then such objects can have certain attributes (which can be abstracted from these objects) and not have others.  It is even possible that such objects can have neither certain attributes nor their negations attributable to them (consider Brouwer's critiques of the law of excluded middle).

Comment: let me quote from van Heijenoort (FROM FREGE TO GODEL: A Sourcebook in Mathematical Logic,pg. 125) Russell's own formulation of the paradox: "Let w be the predicate: to be a predicate that cannot be predicated of itself.  Can w be predicated of itself?  From each answer the opposite follows.  Therefore we must conclude that w cannot be a predicate.  Likewise there is no class (as a totality) of those classes which, each taken as a totality, do not belong to themselves.  From this I conclude that under certain circumstances a definable collection [Menge] does not form s totality."

Comment: If the set of all sets not contained in themselves cannot be considered a totality simply because all but one entity (i.e. R) can be collected into a whole without contradiction, isn't it more reasonable to assume that R can neither have '__ is a member of R' nor '__ is not  member of R' attributed to R than to conclude that R is not a totality (the universe V of ZFC is certainly a class of 'sets not contained in themselves' so R does in some sense certainly exist)?

Comment: The condescension is not warranted.  One of the most reasonable solutions to this problem is to reject the Law of the Excluded Middle, by choosing a more physically and psychologically realistic basis for your logic than the Classical 'standard' one.  It is not at all clear that it is not the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, this works, but you need something resembling a reason:

- You can throw out the Law of the Excluded Middle, resulting in a more basic "intuitionistic" logic.
- you can insist upon an inherent ordering in the process of creating sets, leading to the elaborate and unnatural construct of ZFC and its relatives
- you can claim the notion of 'being an element' simply does not apply to certain kinds of objects, including collections that are 'too big' an those that are not "well-founded"
- you can imply that all references in a language have a natural order of resolution, starting with the approach suggested in the question and leading on to Russel's and Quine's elaborate and unnatural notions of 'ramification' to handle more and more special cases.
- you can claim negation is not total and admit to some contradictions into your logic as special cases
- you can go through a massive project of describing all forms of ordering, and seek out a maximal stable model, accepting that containment, being the most basic kind of ordering *must* be isomorphic to that maximal stable model if it proves unique

All of these, and others, work.  And all of them are very hard to accept without a better philosophical basis than the need to solve this issue.

So you have traded no answer for too many answers, and since all of them feel silly, at first blush, you are in no better stead.  It remains true that logic in the thoroughgoing classical sense cannot be right about our notions of containment, universality, and negation all as we naively understand them -- in a fully resolved and unchanging Platonic realm.  Some part of our natural model is not naturally correct.

The paradox is then what part of your naive and natural understanding you want to discard in order to feel safe, and how we can achieve agreement on something so basic, so that the evolution of math can move forward.  And it is no easier to solve than the original problem.

The modern 'solution' has been to bring up all of these solutions and impose one of them by force of numbers -- a bizarre political process alien to the notion of mathematics itself.

Answer (score 0):

Bertrand Russell had discovered an inconsistency Frege's yet-to-be-published axiomatization of set theory. Using Frege's axioms, Russell demonstrated that  the set of all sets that are not elements of themselves could be both proven to exist and not to exist. Subsequent axiomatizations of set theory have managed to avoid this problem.

Note that the problem is not one of self-reference. It can be trivially shown that, for any binary relation R, there does not exist x such that, for all y, yRx iff not yRy.